# on dom ready remove existing html attribute and add mine

Tags: javascript, jquery

My generated portion of page source is

```
<a target="_blank" href="/img/image001.png">
    <img width="286" height="171" alt="" src="/img/image001.png">
</a>
```

and I need on page load to replace this a target with a rel so above link should be

```
<a rel="lightbox" href="/img/image001.png">
    <img width="286" height="171" alt="" src="/img/image001.png">
</a>
```

I trid with after `</body>`

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
       $('a[_blank]').removeAttr('_blank').attr("rel=","lightbox");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't put the script *outside* the `body` tag. Just put it at the end of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) - you need to use the attribute name along with attribute value, also to remove you need to use the attribute name not value.

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target').attr("rel","lightbox");
```

Your code looks for an anchor element with attribute `_blank` and then removes it, a anchor element like `<a _blank href="/img/image001.png">`

Also as @PaulDraper suggested move the `script` inside the `body` element

Comment: @PaulDraper just somebody having fun

Comment: Just wondering, because I was getting ready to post the same thing, but then you did.

Comment: @PaulDraper - yea; I don't get that either? There are some real a******s on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready({
   $('a[target=_blank]').attr('rel', 'lightbox');
})
```